# Flash Builder fail to export release Build

Tags: air, flash-builder, release

I am having this desktop project which contains a native extension, when I run it there is absolutely no problem, and the native extension works fine, 
But when I try to export a release build It shows this error message "Native extensions are being used in the project but are not supported by the AIR package type. Runtime issues can occur."

Flash Builder 4.6, Windows 7 x64

I have seen some answers, saying it's a bug on 4.6, so I tried on 4.7 and still having the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use ANEs on the desktop, you need to publish the app as a native installer rather than an AIR installer.

On the first page of the publish wizard there is an option "Export as:" - select "Signed native installer".

You will also need to amend the app descriptor file to include the extended desktop as a profile:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

Comment: yep, that works, thanks @Lee but I need to ask this, what's the difference ? Between the native installer and AIR installer ?

Comment: Native installer is just like any 'normal' windows installer - it installs an .exe file (embedded with air app) rather than an .air file. So windows treats it as a standalone program rather than as something to be run inside the AIR player